# reference request Schur Zassenhaus Theorem

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

I am looking for a reference for the Schur Zassenhaus Theorem, saying that any normal Hall subgroup admits a complement.

An on-line search show that it is supposed to be in "The theory of groups" by Zassenhaus himself, but since I don't have the book I was hoping that someone can give a more exact Theorem or section in the book I should refer to.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is Theorem 25 on page 132 of said book.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft , thank you, but this book have two different editions, one by Dover and one by AMS Chelsea. Which edition did you mean?

Comment: The Chelsea one.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft , thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Many (but not all) books of Group Theory / Algebra include this theorem with proof, but in my opinion, the book *Finite Group Theory* by Martin Isaacs gives very elegant, natural, motivational proof of it.

Although it is lengthy (p. 75-80), it is certainly written by author by keeping in mind the audience - undergraduate students, and is written in such a way that if one reads, one gets feel of *a lecture on the topic with neat explanation of proof, reachable to undergraduates*

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

See Section 6.2 in The Theory of Finite Groups: An Introduction, by Kurzweil and Stellmacher

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in Section 6.6(pg 186) in Charles Weibel's book 'An Introduction to Homological Algebra'